# Get a column as NULL even if it's not found inside IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT numit,id FROM pecas where numit in (40363, 40366, 40310, 40320, 40362, 40364, 40385, 40415);
```

And the result I've got:

```
numit | id
40363   50
40362   65
```

I would like to get all 'numit' values inside IN clause and replace 'id' column as NULL if it doesn't find any id for that.Like this:

```
numit | id
40362   65
40363   50
40366   NULL
40310   NULL
40320   NULL
40364   NULL
40385   NULL
40415   NULL
```

Comment: From where you are getting the values inside `IN` clause?

Comment: I think you need left join here.

Comment: It's actually from another column of my table. A column called 'itext'. @AnkitBajpai

Comment: Come on. Stop being so mysterious. Give us that one too. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @BrunoIenne, Is itext on same table or a different table?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai same table

Comment: I think you need to post the whole table structure and data. Please provide the sample data.

Comment: @forpas, How do you know that only Strawberry have downvoted it.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai there are ways to find out.

Comment: @forpas, I guess you have now realised, what was wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest I've come to so far. It needs to create a pseudo table with all the values from the `IN` clause to be able to hae them in the result. Of course, if the `IN` clause values can be fetched as a list of rows from same/another table, it could be simplified (but if the case, you need to edit your question).

```
SELECT p.numit, p.id FROM pecas p WHERE p.numit IN (40363, 40366, 40310, 40320, 40362, 40364, 40385, 40415)
UNION
  SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT 40363 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40366 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40310 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40320 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40362 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40364 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40385 AS numit, NULL AS id
      UNION
      SELECT 40415 AS numit, NULL AS id
    ) t WHERE t.numit NOT IN (SELECT p2.numit FROM pecas p2 WHERE p2.numit IN (40363, 40366, 40310, 40320, 40362, 40364, 40385, 40415))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join if numit data in where clause is coming from some another table like this.

```
    SELECT
    product_name,
    order_id
FROM
    production.products p
LEFT JOIN sales.order_items o ON o.product_id = p.product_id
 where o.product_id in(40363, 40366, 40310, 40320, 40362, 40364, 40385, 4041,4363, 466, 310, 1320, 4032, 40364, 440385, 41041)
ORDER BY
    order_id;
```

[image: using left join]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can first use the UNION clause to combine them and then fetch the maximum ID as below -

```
SELECT numit, MAX(id)
FROM (SELECT numit,id
      FROM pecas
      WHERE numit in (SELECT itext FROM pecas)
      UNION
      SELECT itext, NULL
      FROM pecas) T
GROUP BY numit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
select numit, 
case id in (40363, 40366, 40310, 40320, 40362, 40364, 40385, 40415) then id
  else Null 
    end id
from pecas
```